# What is the point of PHP's SplDoublyLinkedList class, and more importantly, Linked Lists in general?

Tags: php, data-structures, linked-list, spl

On a quest to expand my programming prowess, I've delved ever-so-slightly into [The Standard PHP Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php).  This led to my discovery of the [`SplDoublyLinkedList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) class.  From there I read the descriptions of [Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Doubly-linked_vs._singly-linked) and [Doubly Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-linked_list) on Wikipedia.

I understand how they work...  But I cannot conceive of a reason WHY we need it—or better yet a practical example of `SplDoublyLinkedList` since we have indexed and associative arrays in PHP.

How are Linked Lists normally used in-and-out of PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SPL data structures reduce memory consumption and improve performance. Good explanations:

> Data structures are inherently language-independent and exist as a set of logical concepts based in mathematics. These containers use different algorithms as appropriate to maximize efficiency.
>
> For example, if you don't need the hash map capabilities of an associative array -- that is, if you aren't using the array key for a specific purpose and only need an enumerated array -- SplFixedArray (formerly SplFastArray, currently undocumented) may be a suitable replacement. The only caveat is that the size of the array is fixed, meaning that you must specify the size when you instantiate the class and an error will occur if you attempt to store more than that number of elements. This is the reason that, on average, it performs better than standard PHP arrays.

http://web.archive.org/web/20130805120049/http://blueparabola.com/blog/spl-deserves-some-reiteration

> Within the C code that makes up the PHP interpreter, arrays are implemented as a data structure called a hash table or hash map. When a value contained within an array is referenced by its index, PHP uses a hashing function to convert that index into a unique hash representing the location of the corresponding value within the array.
>
> This hash map implementation enables arrays to store an arbitrary number of elements and provide access to all of those elements simultaneously using either numeric or string keys. Arrays are extremely fast for the capabilities they provide and are an excellent general purpose data structure.
>
> In computer science, a list is defined as an ordered collection of values. A linked list is a data structure in which each element in the list includes a reference to one or both of the elements on either side of it within the list. The term “doubly-linked list” is used to refer to the latter case. In the SPL, this takes the form of the class SplDoublyLinkedList.... It makes sense to use lists when the number of elements to be stored is not known in advance and the elements only need to be accessed by sequential position.

http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/

Comment: This is the best answer on here, and a good one to understand the purpose of these data structures. However, things are not as simple as this answer implies. Just based on the concept of what a double linked list is and what a hash table is (how arrays are implemented in PHP), one would expect that a double linked list could save a LOT of memory over an array. However in my testing, I run out of memory at about the spot with either. Which leads me to believe the doubly linked lists are implemented very stupidly in PHP.

Comment: I also tried making my own singly linked list class with a keen eye to conserving memory. Somehow I am running out of memory at about the same spot as if I use a normal PHP array, which is very bizarre. This leads me to suspect the internals of PHP use PHP arrays in unexpected places. It's just a guess, but not sure what else to think. BTW I am using PHP 5.3.2, so hopefully newer versions are better about this, but I don't know. The point is, if you are going to use a data structure other than the PHP array for performance reasons, make sure you measure the performance to make sure it helps.

Comment: As of PHP 7, arrays use real internal arrays to store the order of elements. And arrays that use the common case of integer keys in ascending order have no underlying hashtable. https://www.npopov.com/2014/12/22/PHPs-new-hashtable-implementation.html#packed-hashtables

Answer (score 4):

According To [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list),

> The principal benefit of a linked list
>   over a conventional array is that the
>   order of the linked items may be
>   different from the order that the data
>   items are stored in memory or on disk.
>   For that reason, linked lists allow
>   insertion and removal of nodes at any
>   point in the list, with a constant
>   number of operations.
>
> On the other hand, linked lists by
>   themselves do not allow random access
>   to the data, or any form of efficient
>   indexing. Thus, many basic operations
>   — such as obtaining the last node of
>   the list, or finding a node that
>   contains a given datum, or locating
>   the place where a new node should be
>   inserted — may require scanning most
>   of the list elements.

So to answer your question, I have no idea. :)

Comment: What it's saying is that linked lasts have fast insertion and removal, whereas in a conventional array, elements have to be shuffled around or the array has to be copied and expanded. PHP's "array" however, is *not* a conventional array.

Comment: someone found a use for SplDoublyLinkedList: from php 5.3.0 to php7.* to php8.alpha, you can use SplDoublyLinkedList to upgrade from www-data access to ***root*** access if you're running php-fpm: https://github.com/cfreal/exploits/blob/master/php-SplDoublyLinkedList-offsetUnset/exploit.php  / https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81026 - lets say you're on a shared webhost and they refuse to give you root access to the *shared* webhost server... or if you're the maintainer of a Composer project, and 1 of your users refuse to give you root access to their server... yeah

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, **SplDoublyLinkedList** are objects, as such

- they can be extended, so you can override their methods (you may for example return all strings uppercased, etc)
- the interfaces they implement can be checked like in `myfunc( SplDoublyLinkedList $var ) ...`
- they're passed as reference by default
- etc.

Secondly, **SplDoublyLinkedList** accept iteration modes, so you can delete your items on the go, and switch direction without reordering the array or complicating your code:

> SplDoublyLinkedList::**IT_MODE_LIFO** (Stack style)
>
> SplDoublyLinkedList::**IT_MODE_FIFO** (Queue style) The behavior of the
> iterator (either one or the other)
>
> SplDoublyLinkedList::**IT_MODE_DELETE** (Elements are deleted by the
> iterator)
>
> SplDoublyLinkedList::**IT_MODE_KEEP** (Elements are traversed by
> the iterator)

The above quotation is from http://simpletechinfo.com/SplDoublyLinkedList which contains some code samples.

There are other perks (like foreach not having to do a copy in memory of all the data, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right, and it just isn't very useful.

There are many uses of linked lists in theory (notably the dancing links). But most of them involves either storing and cloning its iterators elsewhere, access the content in more than two directions, or splitting and merging the lists. SplDoublyLinkedList seemed not to have those.

If it's not for algorithms, one use is to allow an object to remove the reference of itself in some list in constant time, freeing its memory and without shuffling the list (by hashing or swapping with the last item) after insertion or deletion. But this requires storing an iterator of the list in those objects.

Without those functionalities, they just behave like two deques. If you only need to access items using the iterator, they are like two stacks. One better way in single threaded simple cases, barring not already wrapped in a class, is just to use two stacks (maybe fixed arrays, or both ends of the same array). Pop from one stack and push it to another whenever you want the iterator to move, and the top of one stack is the current item. If you also need to access the head and tail, you'll need to replace the stacks with deques.

But if you want to implement stacks or deques themselves without knowing the maximum size, or even to allocate nodes of normal linked lists (in a language without those libraries like in PHP), the good way is to chain some fixed arrays together, using doubly linked lists without those features. Somehow you'll still need it.

The PHP documentation itself, like the Java one, suggests they are supposed to be just a deque supporting some extra weird features, not even two deques (I think). Don't use them if you really need doubly linked lists.

Answer (score 0):

They're there because many programmers comming from other languages are used to them where arrays have fixed sizes and you have to take care of memory managment.
So for PHP they're just another tool. They're implemented because many algorithms & pattern relay on lists and so they don't need to be changed to php-arrays.

Comment: Is this based on assumption?  It seems a stretch that an unneeded data structure--one that only exists to appease programmers transitioning to PHP from another language--would be implemented in the SPL...

Comment: They're implemented in the SPL as custom php-written implementations are far less efficient. The php community could live without them for years. And lists are sure one of the most important data structures used. Same applies for classes for example - you don't need them to write programms but they sure do help but they're a tool too.

Comment: Okay I'll bite.  They are not necessary (obviously since I've gotten on so long without them), but do you have an example of how they could make my life easier?  You've compared them to classes.  Classes make my life approximately nine billion times easier.  How and where does a linked list fit in PHP?

Comment: They don't make life easier in PHP. In PHP you can add new entries to an array like '$array[] = $object;' without having to check for indexes and array size (IndexOutOfBoundException in Java I think). But you can't do this in any compiled language. There arrays have fixed sizes. This is where lists come into play - they don't have a fixed size and can be extended without expansive copying the complete array into a bigger one. To understand the real advantage you've to unterstand how arrays and lists work in any compiled language as they're way more restrictive.

Comment: Don't get me wrong...  **I'm** obviously the one who doesn't get it.  But your last comment confuses me.  "They don't make life easier in PHP." and "To understand the real advantage you've to unterstand how arrays and lists work in any compiled language."  So is there, or is there not a real advantage?

Comment: The advantage over arrays isn't that clear in php as php's arrays are more powerfull. In any compiled language when you create an array you have to specify how many entries it will be able to take. If you want to make this array larger, you have to copy it into a larger one (which takes quite a long time). Lists don't have this size limit. In PHP you don't specify the the array size - they extend automatically. So yes - there is no real benefit *in PHP*. In PHP they're there because they're a standard tool in almost every other language.

Comment: Basically yes. In my understanding the spl is a collection of tools everyone's free to use. You can't even say lists are better then arrays in general, they're a great tool when the situation requires them. The (only, important) benefit they have in general isn't there in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, Lists are an alternative to fixed arrays which are common in other languages. But one important aspect that is often overlooked - you can insert or remove an element from anyplace within a list very efficiently.

Why would this be important? Let's say you have several items that you want to maintain sorted in a array, perhaps so you don't have to sort them later or just to minimize search time. In this instance a List can be a very powerful tool. Especially for very large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are writing a web application in order to make a website look and act like a book (like epub online). A collapsible TOC (table of contents) would provide random access.  The linked list would provide a *convenient* way to implement "next page" and "previous page" buttons. Next and Previous could be implemented in other ways.  The linked list would make it a snap.